# How do I define nested child routes in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have the app structure as follows

```
.
├── photos
├── posts
├── users
│   ├── detail
│   │   ├── address
│   │   ├── family
│   │   ├── information
│   │   └── phones
│   ├── friends
│   └── profile
└── videos
```

To create the nested routes, I prefer routes of same level at their own level.

For example:

first level routes go in the root routes. second level routes go to the users routes and third level goes to the detail route.

so the root routes looks like this,

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'photos',
    component: PhotosComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'posts',
    component: PostsComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'users',
    component: UserListComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'user/:username',
    component: UserComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'videos',
    component: VideosComponent
  }
]
export const AppRoutes = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);


// and the for the user routes,


const userRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'detail',
    component: DetailComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'friends',
    component: FriendsComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'profile',
    component: ProfileComponent
  }
]
export const UserRoutes = RouterModule.forChild(userRoutes);

// and for the detail routes,


const detailRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'address',
    component: AddressComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'family',
    component: FamilyComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'info',
    component: InformationComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'phones',
    component: PhonesComponent
  }
]
export const DetailRoutes = RouterModule.forChild(detailRoutes);
```

How do I mix up the given routes?
I want the route to be `/users/:username/detail/info` but can't figure out how to couple them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to set the children of each routes by using the `children`attribute. If you want to keep them in separate files I guess you could export the const array of `Routes` (not the `RouterModule`) and import them in order to use them by doing something like this :

**user.routes**

```
export const userRoutes : Routes = [
  {
    path: 'detail',
    component: DetailComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'friends',
    component: FriendsComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'profile',
    component: ProfileComponent
  }
]
```

**app.routes**

```
import {userRoutes} from './user/user.routes'

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'photos',
    component: PhotosComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'posts',
    component: PostsComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'users',
    component: UserListComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'user/:username',
    component: UserComponent,
    children: [userRoutes[0]]
  },
  {
    path: 'videos',
    component: VideosComponent
  }
]
export const AppRoutes = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Comment: It should be `children: userRoutes` instead of `children: userRoutes[0]`? Anyway an exception is thrown on navigating to `/users/myusername/detail/info` as  `Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'InformationComponent'`. I have a router-outlet and it works on `routerLink` but not on browser navigation.

Comment: If all the `userRoutes` are specific to `user/:username`  then yes. The error is probably thrown because you're missing a `<router-outlet>` to load the children in the `UserComponent`

Comment: When you use `routerLink` to navigate to the page the children are properly loaded but not when your enter the url ?

Comment: Yes! That is the scenario

Comment: I just tested it on my side every thing is working fine, it is weird that it would not load on url but can when navigating via `routerLink`.

Comment: can you share a working plunk/repo? If you do, I would figure out myself the cause.

Comment: I completely forgot to add the example... I just did it in your featured question. (And added some extra explanations :-) )